# Looking for a Cocoa Google Maps wrapper framework

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, google-maps, frameworks

OSX question, not iOS.

I've been searching for a framework to get easy access to the full (or at least the most important functions)of the V3 API Google Maps within a WebView. 
From what I've read so far it should be technically possible. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/ObjCFromJavaScript.html

I found a nice little simple tutorial on V2 which works great.
http://www.josephcrawford.com/macdev-articles/google-maps-in-a-cocoa-application/

Now before I start re-inventing the wheel and coding everything from scratch (callbacks from map-pins etc.). Is there nothing open source or similar around?

I'm surprised I could not find much on that subject since having a MapView in Cocoa OSX sounds like something many people would find useful theses days.

Thanks for any pointer to an open source project, tutorial or what may be floating around which I could not find.

meanwhile I found this open source project which seems useful to learn how to do it:
https://github.com/nst/CocoaSlideShow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this pretty nice Wrapper which does 100% the same like the iOS MKMapKit:

https://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Google Mapki](http://mapki.com/wiki/Main_Page)? It documents unofficial Google Maps API features. There is an Cocoa Touch example on Kadir Pekel's blog [here](http://blog.kadirpekel.com/2010/05/30/drawing_routes_onto_mkmapview_using_unofficial_google_maps_directions_api/). Though it might be difficult to adopt the example to Cocoa since it makes use of MKMapView.

Answer (score 0):

Try here [programmable web](http://www.programmableweb.com) i could not see what you want but there are at least two objective-c wrappers for other popular api's, not google maps tho,  and so it might be a starting point.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure you need a framework to do this. Did you have a look at the link below?

http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html

Then all you need is generate the HTML from your code and load it with UIWebView's `loadRequest`.

That's what i did in my iPhone project, worked like a charm.

Comment: Well if you read carefully you'll see that this question is about mac OSX and not iOS. Yes it's simple with iOS, but I need to create a desktop application for mac. It's also fairly easy to have it done in OSX, with a webview component and then hook the javascript with the ObjC... but it's a lot of work thats why I was looking around for a framework. But no luck so far.